# user ID and Dropdown sql php server side

Tags: php, sql, wampserver

the code for the view page:

```
  <table id='display'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
            <th>TELEFON</th>
            <th>FAKS</th>
            <th>E-MAIL</th>
            <th>DATA</th>
            <th>PURPOSE</th>
            <th>ACTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$connect){
            die(mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_select_db("permohonan_data");
        $option = '';
        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pemohon ORDER BY id DESC");

    $option .='<select>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['unit']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['telefon']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['faks']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['purpose']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $option .="<option value='" .$row['action']. "'>".$row['action']."</option>"?></td>
    </tr>

<?php
}
    $option .='</select>';
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

the ouput:

[image]

the full detail contains id, name, position, department, institute, email, telefon and so on which doesnt show on the table because of lack of space. my question is, how when I clicked the ID number(auto increrment) of any user, I could see the full details of the user? like in a popup form?

and my dropdown for action column are empty, supposedly have 'approve' and 'disapprove' option but I didnt know how to insert that because its for admin to valid the thing, not the user. so I can't put the option on the client side where the user is. how can I create a new client side just for admin?

idk. please help. :(

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
```

to

```
<td><?php echo "<a href='full_details.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['id']."</a>" ?></td>
```

create a page called full_details.php and use the id to query the db

Comment: I change the code, I made a new page, but I still have no idea how to query the id.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do that.
using a click event you can send id to a "full_details" page and show using a popup the data that page returns back.

See here: [jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

To use jquery you have include it on your page using  tag and after that you can write your own function to receive click action on the id and after that you can send async request to your page and show the result without reload the page.

Comment: I don't know how to use JQuery. you need to install it first right?

Comment: See here: http://jquery.com/
To use jquery you have include it on your page using `<script>` tag and after that you can write your own function to receive click action on the id and after that you can send async request to your page and show the result without reload the page.

Comment: I did the following, but I still didnt know how to edit my code. can you give me example?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ here you can find code, documentation and example.